# can Shibboleth work directly based on oracle database and without a LDAP

Tags: shibboleth

can Shibboleth work without a LDAP, but directly based on oracle database?

Answer (score 2):

It can if you're willing to implement your own JAAS module for the [UsernamePassword](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPAuthUserPass) authentication, or you can write your own code for [External Authentication](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPAuthExternal) for the IdP.

However, if you're using just the code that ships with the IdP, then even if you want to use Oracle or another database for your user attributes in `attribute-resolver.xml`, then you'll *still* need some kind of authentication mechanism like LDAP or Kerberos.

It's a total pain, especially for test or proof-of-concept systems.